# How to enable MultiAZ for an RDS Instance using Boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-rds, aws-sdk, boto3

I wanted to enable the multi-az feature for an rds instance using Boto3.But it is not getting done by using the script.Also I updated my policy for rds instances but still it is not getting updated.I am using the following script.

```
    modified_rds_attributes = rds_conn_boto3.modify_db_instance(DBInstanceIdentifier=id, MultiAZ=True).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [RDS API docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_ModifyDBInstance.html), this change will not occur until the next maintenance window unless you specify the `ApplyImmediately` parameter.  So, this:

```
rds_conn_boto3.modify_db_instance(DBInstanceIdentifier=id, MultiAZ=True, ApplyImmediately=True)
```

Should cause the change to happen immediately.

Comment: Yup,It works now,Are there any negative Consequences of using 'ApplyImmediately =True' tag ?

Comment: The performance of the DB instance will be impacted somewhat by the change to MultiAZ.  It will be temporary and the total length of time depends on many factors such as the size and type of the instance.  So, if you are ok with that happening right now, ``ApplyImmediately`` is fine.  If you would prefer to have that happen at a scheduled maintenance window then omit the parameter.